# to prevent duplicate records entry in sqlserver2008

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am coding on an VSAT application using VB.NET. the string which I received is stored in database current table. I also want the same string stored in history table but in 15 mins interval only one record have to save in history table. how can it be possible. please help me. 
My code is

Dim DecodeString As String
        Dim DataSplit As String()
        Dim date1split As String()

```
    DecodeString = strTempString.Substring(1)
    DecodeString = strTempString
    DataSplit = DecodeString.Split(",")
    date1split = DataSplit(2).Split("/")

    DataSplit(2) = date1split(1) & "/" & date1split(0) & "/" & date1split(2)


    DataSplit(3) = Format(Now, "hh:mm:00")

    If Now.Minute Mod 1 = 0 Then
        If Now.Minute >= 0 And Now.Minute <= 14 Then
            DataSplit(3) = Format(Now, "hh:00:00")

        ElseIf Now.Minute >= 15 And Now.Minute <= 29 Then
            DataSplit(3) = Format(Now, "hh:15:00")

        ElseIf Now.Minute >= 30 And Now.Minute <= 44 Then
            DataSplit(3) = Format(Now, "hh:30:00")

        ElseIf Now.Minute >= 45 And Now.Minute <= 59 Then
            DataSplit(3) = Format(Now, "hh:45:00")
        End If
    End If




    If strTempString.StartsWith("^") And strTempString.EndsWith("$") And strTempString.Length = 285 Then

        Try

            Using sqlconn As New SqlConnection("Server=YOGESHMSPL-PC; DataBase=MSPLKBJNL; User Id=sa; Pwd=mspl123")

                sqlconn.Open()

                Dim str1 As String = ""
                str1 = "begin tran;"
                ds.Clear()
                da = New SqlDataAdapter("Select * From CurrentDataCR Where mst_remote_station_id= '" & DataSplit(1) & "'", sqlconn)
                da.Fill(ds)




                If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then


                    str1 &= ("Insert Into CurrentDataCR (mst_remote_station_id,date1,time1,UpStreamLevel,UpStreamLevelMin,UpStreamLevelMax, UpStreamSensorFail,UpStreamLevelAlarm,DownStreamLevel,DownStreamLevelMin,DownStreamLevelMax,DownStreamSensorFail,DownStreamLevelAlarm,TotalDischarge,TotalGates,Gate1Pos,Gate1SetPoint,Gate1Opening,Gate1Alarm,Gate1ElectricalAlarm,Gate1Mode,Gate2Pos,Gate2SetPoint,Gate2Opening,Gate2Alarm,Gate2ElectricalAlarm,Gate2Mode,Gate3Pos,Gate3SetPoint,Gate3Opening,Gate3Alarm,Gate3ElectricalAlarm,Gate3Mode,Gate4Pos,Gate4SetPoint,Gate4Opening,Gate4Alarm,Gate4ElectricalAlarm,Gate4Mode,InvtGenSignals,GeneratorSignals,OtherSignals,SupplyVoltage) values ('" & DataSplit(1) & "','" & DataSplit(2) & "','" & DataSplit(3) & "','" & DataSplit(5) & "','" & DataSplit(6) & "','" & DataSplit(7) & "','" & DataSplit(8) & "','" & DataSplit(9) & "','" & DataSplit(10) & "','" & DataSplit(11) & "','" & DataSplit(12) & "','" & DataSplit(13) & "','" & DataSplit(14) & "','" & DataSplit(15) & "','" & DataSplit(22) & "','" & DataSplit(23) & "','" & DataSplit(24) & "','" & DataSplit(25) & "','" & DataSplit(26) & "','" & DataSplit(27) & "','" & DataSplit(28) & "','" & DataSplit(29) & "','" & DataSplit(30) & "','" & DataSplit(31) & "','" & DataSplit(32) & "','" & DataSplit(33) & "','" & DataSplit(34) & "','" & DataSplit(35) & "','" & DataSplit(36) & "','" & DataSplit(37) & "','" & DataSplit(38) & "','" & DataSplit(39) & "','" & DataSplit(40) & "','" & DataSplit(41) & "','" & DataSplit(42) & "','" & DataSplit(43) & "','" & DataSplit(44) & "','" & DataSplit(45) & "','" & DataSplit(46) & "','" & DataSplit(60) & "','" & DataSplit(61) & "','" & DataSplit(62) & "','" & DataSplit(63) & "')")
                Else
                    str1 &= ("Update CurrentDataCR set mst_remote_station_id= '" & DataSplit(1) & "',date1='" & DataSplit(2) & "',time1='" & DataSplit(3) & "',UpStreamLevel='" & DataSplit(5) & "',UpStreamLevelMin='" & DataSplit(6) & "',UpStreamLevelMax='" & DataSplit(7) & "', UpStreamSensorFail='" & DataSplit(8) & "',UpStreamLevelAlarm='" & DataSplit(9) & "',DownStreamLevel='" & DataSplit(10) & "',DownStreamLevelMin='" & DataSplit(11) & "',DownStreamLevelMax='" & DataSplit(12) & "',DownStreamSensorFail='" & DataSplit(13) & "',DownStreamLevelAlarm='" & DataSplit(14) & "',TotalDischarge='" & DataSplit(15) & "',TotalGates='" & DataSplit(22) & "',Gate1Pos='" & DataSplit(23) & "',Gate1SetPoint='" & DataSplit(24) & "',Gate1Opening='" & DataSplit(25) & "',Gate1Alarm='" & DataSplit(26) & "',Gate1ElectricalAlarm='" & DataSplit(27) & "',Gate1Mode='" & DataSplit(28) & "',Gate2Pos='" & DataSplit(29) & "',Gate2SetPoint='" & DataSplit(30) & "',Gate2Opening='" & DataSplit(31) & "',Gate2Alarm='" & DataSplit(32) & "',Gate2ElectricalAlarm='" & DataSplit(33) & "',Gate2Mode='" & DataSplit(34) & "',Gate3Pos='" & DataSplit(35) & "',Gate3SetPoint='" & DataSplit(36) & "',Gate3Opening='" & DataSplit(37) & "',Gate3Alarm='" & DataSplit(38) & "',Gate3ElectricalAlarm='" & DataSplit(39) & "',Gate3Mode='" & DataSplit(40) & "',Gate4Pos='" & DataSplit(41) & "',Gate4SetPoint='" & DataSplit(42) & "',Gate4Opening='" & DataSplit(43) & "',Gate4Alarm='" & DataSplit(44) & "',Gate4ElectricalAlarm='" & DataSplit(45) & "',Gate4Mode='" & DataSplit(46) & "',InvtGenSignals='" & DataSplit(60) & "',GeneratorSignals='" & DataSplit(61) & "',OtherSignals='" & DataSplit(62) & "',SupplyVoltage='" & DataSplit(63) & "'")

                End If


                If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then

                    str1 &= ("Insert Into CurrentDataEscape (mst_remote_station_id,date1,time1,UpStreamLevel,UpStreamLevelMin,UpStreamLevelMax, UpStreamSensorFail,UpStreamLevelAlarm,DownStreamLevel,DownStreamLevelMin,DownStreamLevelMax,DownStreamSensorFail,DownStreamLevelAlarm,TotalDischarge,TotalGates,Gate1Pos,Gate1SetPoint,Gate1Opening,Gate1Alarm,Gate1ElectricalAlarm,Gate1Mode,Gate2Pos,Gate2SetPoint,Gate2Opening,Gate2Alarm,Gate2ElectricalAlarm,Gate2Mode, InvtGenSignals,GeneratorSignals,OtherSignals,SupplyVoltage) values ('" & DataSplit(1) & "','" & DataSplit(2) & "','" & DataSplit(3) & "','" & DataSplit(5) & "','" & DataSplit(6) & "','" & DataSplit(7) & "','" & DataSplit(8) & "','" & DataSplit(9) & "','" & DataSplit(10) & "','" & DataSplit(11) & "','" & DataSplit(12) & "','" & DataSplit(13) & "','" & DataSplit(14) & "','" & DataSplit(21) & "','" & DataSplit(41) & "','" & DataSplit(48) & "','" & DataSplit(49) & "','" & DataSplit(50) & "','" & DataSplit(51) & "','" & DataSplit(52) & "','" & DataSplit(53) & "','" & DataSplit(54) & "','" & DataSplit(55) & "','" & DataSplit(56) & "','" & DataSplit(57) & "','" & DataSplit(58) & "','" & DataSplit(59) & "','" & DataSplit(60) & "','" & DataSplit(61) & "','" & DataSplit(62) & "','" & DataSplit(63) & "')")

                Else
                    str1 &= ("Update CurrentDataEscape set mst_remote_station_id='" & DataSplit(1) & "',date1='" & DataSplit(2) & "',time1='" & DataSplit(3) & "',UpStreamLevel='" & DataSplit(5) & "',UpStreamLevelMin='" & DataSplit(6) & "',UpStreamLevelMax='" & DataSplit(7) & "', UpStreamSensorFail='" & DataSplit(8) & "',UpStreamLevelAlarm='" & DataSplit(9) & "',DownStreamLevel='" & DataSplit(10) & "',DownStreamLevelMin='" & DataSplit(11) & "',DownStreamLevelMax='" & DataSplit(12) & "',DownStreamSensorFail='" & DataSplit(13) & "',DownStreamLevelAlarm='" & DataSplit(14) & "',TotalDischarge='" & DataSplit(21) & "',TotalGates='" & DataSplit(41) & "',Gate1Pos='" & DataSplit(48) & "',Gate1SetPoint='" & DataSplit(49) & "',Gate1Opening='" & DataSplit(50) & "',Gate1Alarm='" & DataSplit(51) & "',Gate1ElectricalAlarm='" & DataSplit(52) & "',Gate1Mode='" & DataSplit(53) & "',Gate2Pos='" & DataSplit(54) & "',Gate2SetPoint='" & DataSplit(55) & "',Gate2Opening='" & DataSplit(56) & "',Gate2Alarm='" & DataSplit(57) & "',Gate2ElectricalAlarm='" & DataSplit(58) & "',Gate2Mode='" & DataSplit(59) & "', InvtGenSignals='" & DataSplit(60) & "',GeneratorSignals='" & DataSplit(61) & "',OtherSignals='" & DataSplit(62) & "',SupplyVoltage='" & DataSplit(63) & "'")

                End If



                'da = New SqlDataAdapter("Select * From HistoryDataCR Where time1 = '" & DataSplit(3) & "'", sqlconn)


                'If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count = "" Then


                'str1 &= ("Insert Into HistoryDataCR (mst_remote_station_id,date1,time1,UpStreamLevel,UpStreamLevelMin,UpStreamLevelMax, UpStreamSensorFail,UpStreamLevelAlarm,DownStreamLevel,DownStreamLevelMin,DownStreamLevelMax,DownStreamSensorFail,DownStreamLevelAlarm,TotalDischarge,TotalGates,Gate1Pos,Gate1SetPoint,Gate1Opening,Gate1Alarm,Gate1ElectricalAlarm,Gate1Mode,Gate2Pos,Gate2SetPoint,Gate2Opening,Gate2Alarm,Gate2ElectricalAlarm,Gate2Mode,Gate3Pos,Gate3SetPoint,Gate3Opening,Gate3Alarm,Gate3ElectricalAlarm,Gate3Mode,Gate4Pos,Gate4SetPoint,Gate4Opening,Gate4Alarm,Gate4ElectricalAlarm,Gate4Mode,InvtGenSignals,GeneratorSignals,OtherSignals,SupplyVoltage) values ('" & DataSplit(1) & "','" & DataSplit(2) & "','" & DataSplit(3) & "','" & DataSplit(5) & "','" & DataSplit(6) & "','" & DataSplit(7) & "','" & DataSplit(8) & "','" & DataSplit(9) & "','" & DataSplit(10) & "','" & DataSplit(11) & "','" & DataSplit(12) & "','" & DataSplit(13) & "','" & DataSplit(14) & "','" & DataSplit(15) & "','" & DataSplit(22) & "','" & DataSplit(23) & "','" & DataSplit(24) & "','" & DataSplit(25) & "','" & DataSplit(26) & "','" & DataSplit(27) & "','" & DataSplit(28) & "','" & DataSplit(29) & "','" & DataSplit(30) & "','" & DataSplit(31) & "','" & DataSplit(32) & "','" & DataSplit(33) & "','" & DataSplit(34) & "','" & DataSplit(35) & "','" & DataSplit(36) & "','" & DataSplit(37) & "','" & DataSplit(38) & "','" & DataSplit(39) & "','" & DataSplit(40) & "','" & DataSplit(41) & "','" & DataSplit(42) & "','" & DataSplit(43) & "','" & DataSplit(44) & "','" & DataSplit(45) & "','" & DataSplit(46) & "','" & DataSplit(60) & "','" & DataSplit(61) & "','" & DataSplit(62) & "','" & DataSplit(63) & "')")

                'Else
                'str1 &= ("Update HistoryDataCR set mst_remote_station_id= '" & DataSplit(1) & "',date1='" & DataSplit(2) & "',time1='" & DataSplit(3) & "',UpStreamLevel='" & DataSplit(5) & "',UpStreamLevelMin='" & DataSplit(6) & "',UpStreamLevelMax='" & DataSplit(7) & "', UpStreamSensorFail='" & DataSplit(8) & "',UpStreamLevelAlarm='" & DataSplit(9) & "',DownStreamLevel='" & DataSplit(10) & "',DownStreamLevelMin='" & DataSplit(11) & "',DownStreamLevelMax='" & DataSplit(12) & "',DownStreamSensorFail='" & DataSplit(13) & "',DownStreamLevelAlarm='" & DataSplit(14) & "',TotalDischarge='" & DataSplit(15) & "',TotalGates='" & DataSplit(22) & "',Gate1Pos='" & DataSplit(23) & "',Gate1SetPoint='" & DataSplit(24) & "',Gate1Opening='" & DataSplit(25) & "',Gate1Alarm='" & DataSplit(26) & "',Gate1ElectricalAlarm='" & DataSplit(27) & "',Gate1Mode='" & DataSplit(28) & "',Gate2Pos='" & DataSplit(29) & "',Gate2SetPoint='" & DataSplit(30) & "',Gate2Opening='" & DataSplit(31) & "',Gate2Alarm='" & DataSplit(32) & "',Gate2ElectricalAlarm='" & DataSplit(33) & "',Gate2Mode='" & DataSplit(34) & "',Gate3Pos='" & DataSplit(35) & "',Gate3SetPoint='" & DataSplit(36) & "',Gate3Opening='" & DataSplit(37) & "',Gate3Alarm='" & DataSplit(38) & "',Gate3ElectricalAlarm='" & DataSplit(39) & "',Gate3Mode='" & DataSplit(40) & "',Gate4Pos='" & DataSplit(41) & "',Gate4SetPoint='" & DataSplit(42) & "',Gate4Opening='" & DataSplit(43) & "',Gate4Alarm='" & DataSplit(44) & "',Gate4ElectricalAlarm='" & DataSplit(45) & "',Gate4Mode='" & DataSplit(46) & "',InvtGenSignals='" & DataSplit(60) & "',GeneratorSignals='" & DataSplit(61) & "',OtherSignals='" & DataSplit(62) & "',SupplyVoltage='" & DataSplit(63) & "'")

                'End If

                'If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count = '' Then
                'str1 &= ("Insert Into HistoryDataEscape (mst_remote_station_id,date1,time1,UpStreamLevel,UpStreamLevelMin,UpStreamLevelMax, UpStreamSensorFail,UpStreamLevelAlarm,DownStreamLevel,DownStreamLevelMin,DownStreamLevelMax,DownStreamSensorFail,DownStreamLevelAlarm,TotalDischarge,TotalGates,Gate1Pos,Gate1SetPoint,Gate1Opening,Gate1Alarm,Gate1ElectricalAlarm,Gate1Mode,Gate2Pos,Gate2SetPoint,Gate2Opening,Gate2Alarm,Gate2ElectricalAlarm,Gate2Mode, InvtGenSignals,GeneratorSignals,OtherSignals,SupplyVoltage) values ('" & DataSplit(1) & "','" & DataSplit(2) & "','" & DataSplit(3) & "','" & DataSplit(5) & "','" & DataSplit(6) & "','" & DataSplit(7) & "','" & DataSplit(8) & "','" & DataSplit(9) & "','" & DataSplit(10) & "','" & DataSplit(11) & "','" & DataSplit(12) & "','" & DataSplit(13) & "','" & DataSplit(14) & "','" & DataSplit(21) & "','" & DataSplit(41) & "','" & DataSplit(48) & "','" & DataSplit(49) & "','" & DataSplit(50) & "','" & DataSplit(51) & "','" & DataSplit(52) & "','" & DataSplit(53) & "','" & DataSplit(54) & "','" & DataSplit(55) & "','" & DataSplit(56) & "','" & DataSplit(57) & "','" & DataSplit(58) & "','" & DataSplit(59) & "','" & DataSplit(60) & "','" & DataSplit(61) & "','" & DataSplit(62) & "','" & DataSplit(63) & "') ")
                'End If


                str1 &= "commit tran;"

                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

                If (sqlconn.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
                    cmd.Connection = sqlconn
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.CommandText = str1
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MessageBox.Show("record inserted successfully")

                    sqlconn.Close()

                End If


            End Using
```

Comment: I think you've forgotten to add your code...

Comment: So many people ask basically this same question and I'm convinced that they give it no prior thought because the answer is obvious.  If you had a cupboard that was only allowed to contain one cup of each colour and you wanted to put a cup into that cupboard, what would you do? You'd look in the cupboard to see whether it already contained a cup of that colour, right? That just common sense.  So then, if you want to add a record to a database that doesn't contain the same value as a record already in the database, what is the obvious thing to do?

Comment: ok i m giving my code, please review it.

Comment: How can WHAT be possible? I don't fully understand what you are asking. Does this have to do with duplicating data that is a Primary Key in the database??? IDK

Answer (score 0):

Why not create an Insert trigger to do the same thing?  In the trigger you can check to see if the history record exists for that time period, and if not, insert it, otherwise update it.  It should be faster than doing multiple data operations back and forth to the server, as well.